# Where are useful message constructors, converters

Tags: ros, c++, pose, message, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm relatively new to coding in/for ROS, and I'm looking at both the Python and the C++ side, but let's focus on C++ here.

There are all those useful classes (which are mappings of the ROS message types), like Pose, Twist, etc. **But where are the related utility functions?**

I mean, by what I've found so far, if I want to construct a Pose object, I have to:

```
geometry_msgs::Pose p;
p.position.x = MYXVAL;
p.position.x = MYYVAL;
p.position.x = MYZVAL;
p.orientation.x = ORXVAL;
p.orientation.y = ORYVAL;
p.orientation.z = ORZVAL;
p.orientation.w = ORWVAL;
```

Why can't I just do:

```
geometry_msgs::Pose p(geometry_msgs::Point(MYXVAL, MYYVAL, MYZVAL), geometry_msgs::Quaternion(ORXVAL, ORYVAL, ORZVAL, ORWVAL));
```

(which would of course be even shorter with the proper `include`s and `using namespace` declaration).

And where are my usual utility functions, like `Vector3`<->`Quaternion` or maybe `Twist`(Position+Facing)<->`Pose`(Position+Orientation)?

I could write the convenience constructors (*which one would expect to be provided*) myself, of course, but that's not the point of using a library like ROS/roscpp.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70102/where-are-useful-message-constructors,-converters/) by [nevik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5620/nevik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2013-07-31

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might need to upgrade to a newer ROS version. [This ticket](https://github.com/ros/genmsg/issues/25) says that copy constructors have been available for a while.

Anyway, ROS C++ message classes are auto-generated from *.msg files. See the [genmsg](http://www.ros.org/wiki/genmsg?distro=groovy) package. The generator can't insert convenience functions to convert to and from related message types because it doesn't know what's related and what's not.  You'd have to write that yourself.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nevik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5620/nevik/) on 2013-07-31**:
While I can see that the code generator cannot add semantically meaningful conversion functions, I'd expect some kind of constructor that takes a list of all attributes, like in the case of a Point: `Point(x, y, z)`. Naturally, I *can* create them, but I'd prefer not to :/

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2013-08-01**:
Right. And those constructors *should* be available. Point(1,2,3) is even one of the test cases referenced in the ticket I linked. If you're on the current version of ROS and you cannot use Point(1,2,3), it's a bug and the ticket needs to be refiled.

**Comment by [nevik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5620/nevik/) on 2013-08-01**:
That does not seem to work on Fuerte, unfortunately. Due to certain dependencies which don't work (out of the box) with newer ROS version, I cannot currently upgrade to a newer version, sadly. I'll be looking into that though, and hopefully get it done.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually (in regards to your first point), after a couple frustrating hours, I do not believe that this is implemented in the roscpp client libraries.  Check out this issue: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/148.  I do not believe they are planning on implementing it either...

---

Originally posted by [kwiesz91](https://answers.ros.org/users/23432/kwiesz91/) with karma: 78 on 2015-08-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4